# Cannot restore last Chrome session. `Session_` file empty, but the `Tabs_` file preserved

Tags: google-chrome, crash, session

Last time my Chrome browser crashed because there were no free space at $HOME folder. After I opened it (previously freeing about 2G of space at the partition), I was presented with the (usual) "Restore last session" button, which I pressed immediately; however, nothing happened, no tab was restored. I navigated to the `$HOME/.config/google-chrome/Default/Sessions` folder, where I found that my previous `Session_XXXXX` file is empty, whereas the new(er) one is just a couple kilobytes of size. I killed the Chrome with the `chrome://inducebrowsercrashforrealz` browser command, copied the old `Tabs_` file over the smaller one, newer `Session_` over the older null-sized one, and started the browser. Again, "Restore last session" did nothing.

Is there a way to restore the last browser session having only the `Tabs_` file?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

As a workaround, http://lsauer.net/chrome-session-restore/# (kinda) helps in my situation. At the website, tapping `Choose Files` on bottom panel, then selecting the `Tabs_XXXXX` file (that has ~30MB of size), then opening the `Recently closed` pop-up menu at the left of the `Choose Files` button, noticing the maximum number of tabs at very top of the opened menu (`... of all 1208 Tab(s)`), entering this number at the editbox situated right to the `Max #Tabs:` text on the bottom panel, then reopening the `Recently closed` menu (the topmost menu item is now `Open 3208 of all 3208 Tab(s)`), then pressing this item and waiting... until the browser silently crashed. Seems like my 8G RAM is just not enough to open all of them at once. Only about 800 tabs get opened upon next Chrome restart. At least something. But I am searching for the more robust solution.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).